# How do I blacklist a device itself in Ubuntu, not it's kernel module?

Tags: 20.04, sound, kernel, kubuntu, blacklist

I am using **Kubuntu 20.04**. This computer has an internal sound card (PCIX) and my display monitor has a sound device via HDMI. My sound equipment is attached to the internal sound card so it is preferred over the display monitor sound device which is a very poor quality.

In the **Audio system settings module** I have disabled the display sound device. When I boot into Kubuntu all is well and my internal sound card works as it should. After a while at random and especially if the monitor goes to sleep, the display sound device will re-enable itself on it's own, and it will show up as a second device in the system volume control. When this happens, no matter what I do (and I've tried quite a bit) my internal sound card won't operate anymore unless I re-disable the display sound device in the **Audio system settings module** and reboot (logout is insufficient).

I believe what is happening is that the display is deciding to re-initializing it's sound device (perhaps when waking from sleep) which in turn causes Kubuntu to disassociate the **disabled** setting with the newly detected (though identical) sound device thus defaulting to **enabled**. But the underlying problem in my opinion is that subsequently both sound devices seem to share the exact same kernel module.

```
lspci -v

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at df080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
 
03:00.0 Audio device: Creative Labs Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Creative Labs SB1570 SB Audigy Fx
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at df304000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

I am interested in blacklisting **GP104**, but my limited research has shown that only kernel drivers can be blacklisted. That would be counterproductive in this case since it would also disable my desired sound device **SB1570**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The solution is not disabling devices, is using let's say pavucontrol to set the default for the audio, the internal instead of HDMI.

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many times I've tried this. Unless the undesired device is disabled and the OS rebooted (in that order) my internal sound card will not function. If I boot up with both devices enabled, though SB1570 is default in every respect, the sound output won't work from SB1570 unless I reboot as described. I blame the shared kernel modules, but I am not an expert on this topic.

Comment: I assumed you are using alsa?

Answer (score 1):

There is a sub-component used in this setup: 1 of them is using `index=0` and the other is using `index=1`. You need to set

```
options snd_hda_intel index=1
```

(or 0) in the configuration file (`/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`).

Comment: I did this, and while I didn't see the other device auto-enable itself like before, the SB1570 device again stopped playing back audio.